# Infinite loop after adding a dependency

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

When I'm adding dependency `fetchData`, my app becomes an infinite loop.
What am I doing wrong?

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

```
const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [isLoad, setIsLoad] = useState(false);

const incrementPage = () => {
  setPage(page + 1);
};

const fetchData = async () => {
  setIsLoad(true);
  const response = await fetch(
    `${baseURL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${page}`
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  setFilms([...films, ...response.results]);
  setIsLoad(false);
  incrementPage();
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Try wrapping `fetchData` with a `useCallback` hook

Comment: @FLash thanks you, man. I will try

Answer (score 0):

I would place the contents of fetchData into the useEffect instead.

```
const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [isLoad, setIsLoad] = useState(false);

const incrementPage = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
};

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoad(true);
    const response = await fetch(
        `${baseURL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${page}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());
    setFilms([...films, ...response.results]);
    setIsLoad(false);
    incrementPage();
}, [setIsLoad, page, setFilms, setIsLoad, incrementPage]);
```

Then it will automatically fetch new data if 'page' is changed.

Comment: I need to use FetchData on button
Loop continue(